# How many solutions does the following initial value problem have?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How many solutions does the following initial value problem have? Explain why.

$tx'+x=1$ , and initial value is $x(0)=0$

The problem is that at $(0,0)$ the function is not continuous, but there exists only one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has none. Assume there is a solution x(t). then $1=0\cdot x'(0)+x(0)=0+0=0$.

Comment: the professor said there exist only one solution,,,the Hint is: for t near 0 there exist x Diff. s.t. x(0)=0 and tx′+x=1.....

Comment: if some one had same question but different variables its ok,so please post it.

Comment: @axiom_of_choice: By applying your argument to the problem of finding an $x$ such that $2 x x' = 1$ and $x(0)=0$, we could also conclude that this problem does not have any solutions. I do not think that this is a very satisfying answer, since I would consider both $\sqrt{t}$ and $-\sqrt{t}$ as valid solutions to this second problem.